# Populate select2 dropdown with selected value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using a PHP script to edit data that is stored in my database. The data is stored with dynamic rows.

In my script I am also using the Select2 script that makes it possible to search in my dropdown.

The Ajax script I am using to populate is the following:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script> 
    function getName<?php echo $m; ?>() { 
      $.ajax
      ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './get/name/get1.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
          $('#name<?php echo $m; ?>').html(data);
        },
        complete: function(){}
      }); 
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
      getName<?php echo $m; ?>();
    });
</script>
```

In `get1.php` I an using the following statement to select the data:

```
SELECT internal_id, name FROM scu_stock
```

The scu_stock table has the following data:

```
-------------------------
| internal_id |   name  |
|      1      |   One   |
|      2      |   Two   |
|      3      |  Three  |
|      4      |   Four  |
-------------------------
```

The value that I want to represent as the `selected value` is stored in another table. 
scu_address

```
---------------------------------------
| id |  city  | country | internal_id |
| 6  |   aa   |   ww    |      1      |
| 7  |   bb   |   xx    |      2      |
| 8  |   cc   |   yy    |      3      |
| 9  |   dd   |   zz    |      4      |
---------------------------------------
```

When I open `index.php?id=8` I want to see the the data in table scu_stock with the selected value that is called in the scu_address table.

Does someone know how I can realize this?

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
  $statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM scu_address WHERE id = :id");
  $statement->execute(
    array(
      ':id'       =>  $_GET["id"]
    )
  );
  $item_result = $statement->fetchAll();
  $m = 0;
  foreach($item_result as $sub_row)
  {
    $m = $m + 1;
?>
    <tr id="row_id_<?php echo $m; ?>">
      <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
      <td><select style="width:100%" id="name<?php echo $m; ?>" name="name[]" data-srno="<?php echo $m; ?>"></select></td>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../vendors/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $.fn.select2.defaults = $.extend($.fn.select2.defaults, {
          allowClear: true,
          closeOnSelect: true,
          value: 'Name',
          minimumResultsForSearch: 15
        });

        $(document).ready(
          function () {
            var configParamsObj = {
              placeholder: 'Name',
              minimumResultsForSearch: 3
            };
            $("#name<?php echo $m; ?>").select2(configParamsObj);
          });
      </script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script> 
        function getName<?php echo $m; ?>() { 
          $.ajax
          ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './get/name/get1.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
              $('#name<?php echo $m; ?>').html(data);
            },
            complete: function(){}
          }); 
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
          getName<?php echo $m; ?>();
        });
    </script>
    </tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have `<?php echo $m; ?>`? Make a general getter and pass the ID as a value

Comment: In this case I have given an example. I am working with dynamic rows. The code `<?php echo $m; ?>` generates the ID's for the other textboxes and scripts (`name1`, `name2`, `name3` and also `function getName1`, `function getName2`, `function getName3`)

Comment: Let me get this straight... You need to show the selected values from the database in the select2 textbox. Right?

Comment: Thats right ...

Answer (score 0):

To fill the select2 textbox with selected value fetched from the database:

1. Create the PHP variable to fill with the fetched data `$selecteddata = " ";` then fill it to obtain the following format `$selecteddata .="'1','2','3','4'";`
2. After the select2 code add the following script:

   `<script>`

   `$('#select2ID').val([<?php echo $selecteddata ;?>]);`

   `$('#select2ID').trigger('change');`

   `</script>`

By this you will select only the data you fetched so you can edit.